# Python array element assignment

Tags: python, arrays, copy

I am confused with a simple case about array variable assignment in Python, and hope some one could help me check it.

In my understanding, if a is a list, b just copied the reference of a, and when you edit b, a would be modified as well. Meanwhile, you could use the `is` operator to check their ids. For example:

```
a = ["a", ["a", "b"]]
b = a[1]
b.append("c")
```

Then, it would return `True`, when I use

```
In [7]: b is a[1]
Out[7]: True
```

However, if a and b are an arrays,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.identity(3)
b = a[0, :]
```

Afterwards, when I use `is` to check, it returns `False`, but when I edited b, a would be modified as well:

```
In [14]: b is a[1]
Out[14]: False
In [15]: a
Out[15]:
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
In [16]: b
Out[16]: array([0., 1., 0.])
In [17]: b *= 2
In [18]: b
Out[18]: array([0., 2., 0.])
In [19]: a
Out[19]:
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Basically, I think if `is` returns `False`, variables would have different ids and references, which means that they are independent, but it seems wrong right now, could anyone help me to check it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a slice of the array creates a view. `b` and `a[0,:]` are distinct views, even though they view the same part of the array `a`, so their id values are different even though their underlying references are the same.

The id of an object is technically distinct from what it's referencing, so objects with the same id will reference the same data but objects with the same reference don't necessarily have the same id

Comment: Hi Michael, do you mean that only accessing a slice of array will create a view but not in accessing a slice of list? Meanwhile, I am not sure that how 2 variables with different ids could be modified at same time even though they have same reference. Is it a property of dynamic language?

Comment: Python lists don't have views, that's a Numpy feature. 

Two variables with the same reference are pointing to the same data in memory. So modifying that data from one reference is the same as modifying that data from the other, even if the two variables have different IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays work differently than Python lists. In your example, b is a *numpy view* of the first row of a, which is not the same as a pointer to the first element a.

By the way, you can check the id of each of your variables by doing `id(b)` or `id(a[0])` for example.

Comment: Hi Brian, I checked them too. I thought `is` operator has same meaning as checking `id` of variables. But I am confused that how can b and a[1] be modified together with different ids? Does this problem result from numpy or python?